# How to split an HtmlNode by <br> and then extract the InnerText from each split string?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm currently trying with:

```
node.InnerHtml.Split("<br>").Select(s => HtmlNode.CreateNode(s).InnerText).ToList()
```

Which leads to the exception:

> Multiple node elments can't be created

Which seems strange because those split strings have normal text + html elements, following an example of the above node html:

```
Some <span>text</span> here <br>
Some <span>text</span> here 2<br>
Some <span>text</span> here 3<br>
```

Am I missing something? How would you make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it does create a node successfully only if the string start and ends with an html tag, so my new take on solving this is:

```
node.InnerHtml.Split("<br>").Select(s => HtmlNode.CreateNode($"<span>{s}</span>").InnerText).ToList()
```